# How to exclude a commit from git server?

Tags: git

I have already pushed all the changes to the server.

Here is the order of my commits to the server :-

```
Commit G - ......
Commit F - ......
Commit E - .......
**Commit D - .......**
Commit C - .......
Commit B - .......
Commit A - .......
```

Commit G is the one I need to release. But Commit D is buggy I have to get rid of it from this release. but at the same time I don't want to delete it completely I need to keep Commit D for later use.

How will i do it using git?

Comment: By pushed the changes to the server, Do you mean it's published publicly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git revert COMMIT_D_HASH` will introduce a commit that reverts the changes in D.

It will still be in the history.

You will end up with:

```
Revert of Commit D - .....
Commit G - ......
Commit F - ......
Commit E - .......
**Commit D - .......**
Commit C - .......
Commit B - .......
Commit A - .......
```

Comment: Yes, you will then be able to "revert the revert" if D must be reintegrated.